# Basic F# / Rust performance comparison

Tags: performance, rust, f#

this is a simplistic performance test based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlMLB2-G25c which compares the performance of rust vs wasm vs python vs go

the original rust program (from https://github.com/masmullin2000/random-sort-examples) is:

```
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let vec = make_random_vec(1_000_000, 100);
    for _ in 0..250 {
        let mut v = vec.clone();
        // v.sort_unstable();
        v.sort();   // using stable sort as f# sort is a stable sort
    }
}

pub fn make_random_vec(sz: usize, modulus: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut v: Vec<i64> = Vec::with_capacity(sz);
    for _ in 0..sz {
        let x: i64 = random();
        v.push(x % modulus);
    }
    v
}
```

so i created the following f# program to compare against rust

```
open System

let rec cls (arr:int64 array) count =
    if count > 0 then
        let v1 = Array.copy arr
        let v2 = Array.sort v1
        cls arr (count-1)
    else
        ()

let rnd = Random()
let rndArray = Array.init 1000000 (fun _ -> int64 (rnd.Next(100)))
cls rndArray 250 |> ignore
```

i was expecting f# to be slower (both running on WSL2) but got the following times on my Core i7 8th gen laptop

- Rust - around 17 seconds
- Rust (unstable sort) - around 2.7 seconds
- F# - around 11 seconds

my questions:

- is the dotnet compiler doing some sort of optimisation that throws away some of the processing because the return values are not being used resulting in the f# code running faster or am i doing something wrong?
- does f# have an unstable sort function that i can use to compare against the Rust unstable sort?

Comment: Mandatory comment: did you run the Rust code in `--release` mode?

Comment: yes, both rust and dotnet were compiled with the release flag

Comment: These ones don’t seem to do the same.

Comment: I don't think array and vector are the same data structure, also in one code you are doing recursive and rust is one is imperative style. to finish Array.sort of F# is unstable https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#sort. Rust so win by far

Comment: thanks @Stargateur i did not notice that in the rust code, i changed the f# code to use List instead of Array and it takes around 40 seconds to run which makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, F# array and Rust vector are very much the same data structure. List is a whole different thing - it's a singly linked list, very convenient for handling, but terrible for performance. I can't find an equivalent of F# list in Rust standard library. `LinkedList` is closest, but it's doubly linked.

Comment: This comparison is still not like for like however, because the Rust version sorts the vector in place, mutating the original vector, while F# version allocates a new array, leaving the original one untouched. To make this more fair, try `sortInPlace`: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html#sortInPlace

Comment: Or I guess you can just remove `Array.copy` to achieve same effect.

Comment: thanks @Fyodor for the clarification,  removing the Array.copy or using sortInPlace don't make much difference to the speed, still around 10 seconds i.e. about 4 times as long as rust (unstable sort) which is not bad.  i have a python pandas script which takes about 20 minutes to process a 3.5million row file (62 columns),  i converted it to f# and the f# version processes the 3.5m rows in around 60 seconds

Comment: Yes, a few times slower than Rust is about what I would expect.

Comment: On https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html it says: _A contiguous growable array type, written as `Vec<T>`, short for ‘vector’._ This makes it rather comparable to .NET `List<T>`, or `ResizeArray<'T>` in F#. Although the resize capability is not used in the Rust code, thus making it comparable to a simple array.